# Why do we need to define the generic type with the function name other than the parameter signatures in Rust?

Tags: rust

Going over the [generic types chapter of the official Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-01-syntax.html), I noticed that we have to define the generic function as follows:

`fn largest<T>(list: &[T]) -> T {`

My doubt is: why add `<T>` right after `largest`? We don't do that for non-generic functions such as: `fn largest(list: &[i32]) -> i32`.

Answer (score 8):

They mean two different (and equally valid) things

```
fn largest<T>(list: &[T]) -> T
```

This says "`largest` is a function that, for *any* type `T`, takes a slice of `T` and returns a `T`". On the other hand,

```
fn largest(list: &[T]) -> T
```

This function says "`largest` takes a slice of `T` and returns a `T`", where `T` is some specific type in scope. That is, this second definition assumes there's something of the form

```
struct T {}
```

or some other type declaration, alias, or import in scope right now, and `largest` *only* works for that type. Note that `T` is a horrible name for a specific type, but Rust doesn't care about good names. As far as Rust is concerned, `T` is a perfectly valid type. So is `ndscjkdbhsgey`, but please don't name your structs that either. We need the `<T>` to tell Rust "this is not a specific type name; it's a variable, and I'm choosing to call it `T`".

Answer (score 3):

Because you have to create the generic type `T`. `i32` is a predefined type while `T` is one that only exists within the context of that function and you have to define it like a variable for the compiler. It does not have to be `T` and you could have made the function definition be `fn largest<U>(list: &[U]) -> U`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the `<T>` syntax introduces the type `T` in scope so it can be used for parameter types and return type. If you didn't mark the function with `<T>` how would it know what `T` is? It would rely on the type being visible already which is the case for the non-generic function you provided - `i32` is imported by default.

Answer (score 0):

For the same reason we write `<T>` after generic implementations. For example `impl<T> SomeGenericStruct<T>`. If you didn't mark the implementation, or in the case of your question, your function, as a generic with the `<T>` syntax, which is also required of lifetimes such as `<&'a T>`, then the compiler wouldn't treat `T` as a generic.